# Embedding code into an entry

Tags: field, html-entities

I need to embed some coding into an entry, but I'm unsure how to do it.

I understand that I need to put the code into a Plain text field, so I've created a Plain Text field in Settings, but I now don't know how to bring that field into an Entry- I can't see how to select it. All I can select is a Standalone or Informative text content block.

Thanks